# grails app accessing google Spreadsheet

Tags: grails, groovy, gdata

So, have been struggling with this one for close to a week now trying different things, and really need a bit of help.

So, trying to write a quite simple web app that will use a Google spreadsheets as source, and it seems like this should be possible, but I do not seem to be able to get grails to load the necessary classes or libraries.

One of the simpler solutions is one presented by paridhi in this article:
http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2013/05/13/authentication-using-oauth-for-google-drive-application/

Which seems to indicate that all I should have to do (before writing all the code that is) is to add the following to BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile "com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1"
compile "com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta"
compile "com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.14.1-beta"
```

After fiddling about, I tried reinstalling GG, created a new project, and only added those lines to BuildConfig.groovy, and all I am rewarded with is dependency build errors.

```
> objc[1450]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
| Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        [FAILED     ] com.google.gdata#core;1.47.1!core.zip:  (0ms)
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/Documents/grails-work/crTest/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/cache-1.0.1/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/database-migration-1.3.2/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/hibernate-2.2.4/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/resources-1.2/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/tomcat-2.2.4/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.gdata/core/jars/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.gdata/core/bundles/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/src/libs/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/dist/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/plugins/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-core/tags/RELEASE_1.47.1/grails-core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.m2/repository/com/google/gdata/core/1.47.1/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gdata/core/1.47.1/core-1.47.1.zip
        [FAILED     ] com.google.apis#google-api-services-drive;v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta!google-api-services-drive.zip:  (0ms)
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/Documents/grails-work/crTest/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/cache-1.0.1/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/database-migration-1.3.2/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/hibernate-2.2.4/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/resources-1.2/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/tomcat-2.2.4/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive/jars/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive/bundles/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/src/libs/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/dist/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/plugins/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-google-api-services-drive/tags/RELEASE_v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta/grails-google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.m2/repository/com/google/apis/google-api-services-drive/v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/apis/google-api-services-drive/v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
        [FAILED     ] com.google.http-client#google-http-client-jackson;1.14.1-beta!google-http-client-jackson.zip:  (0ms)
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/Documents/grails-work/crTest/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/cache-1.0.1/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/database-migration-1.3.2/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/hibernate-2.2.4/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/resources-1.2/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/tomcat-2.2.4/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson/jars/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson/bundles/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/src/libs/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/dist/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/plugins/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-google-http-client-jackson/tags/RELEASE_1.14.1-beta/grails-google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.m2/repository/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson/1.14.1-beta/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson/1.14.1-beta/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
        :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: com.google.gdata#core;1.47.1!core.zip
        :: com.google.apis#google-api-services-drive;v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta!google-api-services-drive.zip
        :: com.google.http-client#google-http-client-jackson;1.14.1-beta!google-http-client-jackson.zip
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        [FAILED     ] com.google.gdata#core;1.47.1!core.zip:  (0ms)
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/Documents/grails-work/crTest/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/cache-1.0.1/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/database-migration-1.3.2/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/hibernate-2.2.4/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/resources-1.2/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/tomcat-2.2.4/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.gdata/core/jars/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.gdata/core/bundles/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/src/libs/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/dist/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/plugins/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-core/tags/RELEASE_1.47.1/grails-core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.m2/repository/com/google/gdata/core/1.47.1/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gdata/core/1.47.1/core-1.47.1.zip
        [FAILED     ] com.google.apis#google-api-services-drive;v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta!google-api-services-drive.zip:  (0ms)
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/Documents/grails-work/crTest/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/cache-1.0.1/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/database-migration-1.3.2/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/hibernate-2.2.4/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/resources-1.2/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/tomcat-2.2.4/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive/jars/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive/bundles/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/src/libs/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/dist/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/plugins/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-google-api-services-drive/tags/RELEASE_v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta/grails-google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.m2/repository/com/google/apis/google-api-services-drive/v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/apis/google-api-services-drive/v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
        [FAILED     ] com.google.http-client#google-http-client-jackson;1.14.1-beta!google-http-client-jackson.zip:  (0ms)
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/Documents/grails-work/crTest/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/cache-1.0.1/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/database-migration-1.3.2/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/hibernate-2.2.4/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/resources-1.2/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/tomcat-2.2.4/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson/jars/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson/bundles/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/src/libs/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/dist/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/plugins/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-google-http-client-jackson/tags/RELEASE_1.14.1-beta/grails-google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.m2/repository/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson/1.14.1-beta/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson/1.14.1-beta/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
        :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: com.google.gdata#core;1.47.1!core.zip
        :: com.google.apis#google-api-services-drive;v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta!google-api-services-drive.zip
        :: com.google.http-client#google-http-client-jackson;1.14.1-beta!google-http-client-jackson.zip
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        [FAILED     ] com.google.gdata#core;1.47.1!core.zip:  (0ms)
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/Documents/grails-work/crTest/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/cache-1.0.1/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/database-migration-1.3.2/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/hibernate-2.2.4/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/resources-1.2/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/tomcat-2.2.4/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.gdata/core/jars/core-1.47.1.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.gdata/core/bundles/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/src/libs/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/dist/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/plugins/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-core/tags/RELEASE_1.47.1/grails-core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.m2/repository/com/google/gdata/core/1.47.1/core-1.47.1.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gdata/core/1.47.1/core-1.47.1.zip
        [FAILED     ] com.google.apis#google-api-services-drive;v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta!google-api-services-drive.zip:  (0ms)
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/Documents/grails-work/crTest/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/cache-1.0.1/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/database-migration-1.3.2/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/hibernate-2.2.4/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/resources-1.2/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/tomcat-2.2.4/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive/jars/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.apis/google-api-services-drive/bundles/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/src/libs/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/dist/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/plugins/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-google-api-services-drive/tags/RELEASE_v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta/grails-google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.m2/repository/com/google/apis/google-api-services-drive/v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/apis/google-api-services-drive/v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta.zip
        [FAILED     ] com.google.http-client#google-http-client-jackson;1.14.1-beta!google-http-client-jackson.zip:  (0ms)
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/Documents/grails-work/crTest/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/cache-1.0.1/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/database-migration-1.3.2/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/hibernate-2.2.4/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/resources-1.2/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/tomcat-2.2.4/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/projects/crTest/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson/jars/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/lib/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson/bundles/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/src/libs/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/dist/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.grails/2.2.4/cached-installed-plugins/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/springsource/grails-2.2.4/plugins/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== grailsCentral: tried
      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-google-http-client-jackson/tags/RELEASE_1.14.1-beta/grails-google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== localMavenResolver: tried
      /Users/bengtbjorkberg/.m2/repository/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson/1.14.1-beta/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
    ==== mavenCentral: tried
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson/1.14.1-beta/google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.zip
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
        :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: com.google.gdata#core;1.47.1!core.zip
        :: com.google.apis#google-api-services-drive;v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta!google-api-services-drive.zip
        :: com.google.http-client#google-http-client-jackson;1.14.1-beta!google-http-client-jackson.zip
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1
- com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta
- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.14.1-beta
```

============================== EDIT ====================================
Seems like I had added it to the wrong section, now I am getting a slightly different issue about jsr 305

```
Seems like it, now I have another issue, where can I get jsr305 (think that is what it is asking for ....:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;1.3.9: configuration not found in com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;1.3.9: 'compile'. It was required from com.google.http-client#google-http-client;1.14.1-beta compile
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;1.3.9: configuration not found in com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;1.3.9: 'compile'. It was required from com.google.http-client#google-http-client;1.14.1-beta compile
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;1.3.9: configuration not found in com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;1.3.9: 'compile'. It was required from com.google.http-client#google-http-client;1.14.1-beta compile
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
```

=================================EDIT 2 ==========================================
Thank you all those that helped, seems like it was just getting import right, and the jre. So if anyone have the same issue. You need to do two things.

Add to BuildConfig.grove  (under dependencies)

```
compile "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9"
compile "com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1"
compile "com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev72-1.14.2-beta"
compile "com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.14.1-beta"
```

Next, add the correct import line for your controller

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.*
```

My last issue is that eclipse still seems to dislike GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrlbut compiles OK. Hope this helps someone, and thanks again tim_yates

Comment: Did you add them to `plugins` instead of `dependencies`?

Comment: Seems like it, now its complaining about not having jsr 305 (added info to call)

Comment: Adding jsr did not help. Neither did the change from having the compile lines in dependencies (where I am guessing they should be) and plugins

Comment: OK, it has potentially worked, will provide update

Comment: So, after working away it now seems like I have come full circle, kind of. Think it has loaded the four dependencies, but when I try to use the code grails throws an error: unable to resolve class GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl What am I missing?

Comment: Have you added the google repository to your maven repositories in BuildConfig ?